# Dockerfile running piped powershell

Tags: docker, powershell, dockerfile

My Dockerfile contains the following line

```
RUN pwsh -Command Find-Module deployment.aws.applications -AllVersions | Where-Object {[version]$_.Version -ge '5.1.10' -and [version]$_.Version -le '100.0.0'} | ForEach-Object { Install-Module -Name $_.Name -RequiredVersion $_.Version -Repository  ${REPOSITORY} -Scope AllUsers -AcceptLicense -Force }
```

Which outputs:

```
 => [2/2] RUN pwsh -Command Find-Module deployment.aws.applications -AllVersions | Where-Object {[version]$_.Version -ge '5.1.10' -and [version]$_.Version -le '100.0.0'} | ForEach-Object { Install-Module -Name $_.Name -Required  14.0s
 => => # /bin/sh: 1: ForEach-Object: not found
 => => # /bin/sh: 1: Where-Object: not found
```

What looks to be happening is the pipe (|) isn't being seen as a Powershell command. I had wrapped the whole line in quotes, but the Dockerfile args don't get resolved.

To make the whole issue a little more complex, I then want to run mutiple Powershell commands via the one Dockerfile RUN command. Like so:

```
RUN pwsh -Command Find-Module deployment.aws.applications -AllVersions | Where-Object {[version]$_.Version -ge '5.1.10' -and [version]$_.Version -le '100.0.0'} | ForEach-Object { Install-Module -Name $_.Name -RequiredVersion $_.Version -Repository  ${REPOSITORY} -Scope AllUsers -AcceptLicense -Force }  && \
pwsh -Command Find-Module x.y.z -AllVersions | Where-Object {[version]$_.Version -ge '5.1.10' -and [version]$_.Version -le '100.0.0'} | ForEach-Object { Install-Module -Name $_.Name -RequiredVersion $_.Version -Repository  ${REPOSITORY} -Scope AllUsers -AcceptLicense -Force }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Powershell commands are becoming complex, it would be easier to put them into a script and just use `RUN` to execute that script.

**Find-Install-Modules.ps1**

```
Find-Module deployment.aws.applications -AllVersions | Where-Object {[version]$_.Version -ge '5.1.10' -and [version]$_.Version -le '100.0.0'} | ForEach-Object { Install-Module -Name $_.Name -RequiredVersion $_.Version -Repository  ${REPOSITORY} -Scope AllUsers -AcceptLicense -Force }
```

**Dockerfile**

```
ADD Find-Install-Modules.ps1 .
RUN pwsh -File Find-Install-Modules.ps1
```